# How to design n many to many relationship in order make sql query easily

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many, data-modeling, erd

I have 3 many to many relationship between 3 tables following this rule:

- There is a many to many relationship between table A and table B.
- There is a many to many relationship between table A and table C.
- There is a many to many relationship between table B and table C.

I would to use association table between them, but I look for the best way to handle that.
In my mind I think to create mapping table which will contain idA, idB, idC as foreign keys and have one to many relation between each table with the mapping table.

Comment: The text is consistent with the diagram. Any further questions?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl My goal is to use association in order to retrieve for given clinic all doctors with theirs respective treatments. 
Also by given treatment to retrieve all clinics with respective doctors for that treatment.

Answer (score 1):

All relationships are represented *in* tables as associations between columns/values representing entity identifiers. Relationships are not *between* tables - that's a confusion between conceptual modelling (where relationships exist between entities) and physical modelling (where tables can be joined based matching values).

You propose a single ternary relationship table instead of properly implementing 3 separate binary relationship tables. I assume all the columns will be nullable? That's going to prevent you from implementing a primary key, and depending on your DBMS, unique constraints may be problematic too. Not to mention figuring out what it means when all 3 fields in a row are populated.

Do it the right way, and create 3 separate relationship tables in which you at least have a unique constraint on the two entity columns.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I will create 3 separate relationship tables.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we have many-to-many relationship between two tables, a new table is created for the "many-to-many" relationship, where primary keys of both tables are added as foreign keys, you can study it in detail, i'm in the entry level, on the basis of my knowledge i answered.